# Large ratio values ssrs chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart that show the count of number of models for each agency,

The problem is that I have a large difference between the values that makes the report to look not so good.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas of a good way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a logarithmic scale?

With your chart Right-click the y-axis, and click Vertical Axis Properties.
In Axis Options, select Use logarithmic scale.

Leave the Log base text box as 10 (this is the scale most commonly used by logarithmic charts)

[image]

This will display a chart with a scale that goes up by a factor of 10 for each ‘unit’ up, so the distance between 1 and 10 is the same as that between 100 and 1000.

For example the shown dataset is displayed as this chart when using the logarithmic scale

[image]

This method is a simple and recognised way to clearly show values of widely different scales.

**Update**

If want an indicative bar for the vales that are 1 then you could use the expression

```
=iif(Fields!val.Value = 1, Fields!val.Value * 1.1, Fields!val.Value)
```

To make all values that are 1 equal to 1.1 so showing a tiny bar appearing a the bottom of the chart, as seen here

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to change that first 1 to a zero (formatting-wise).  This is partly because you are now using a logarithmic scale and zero and negative values don't really exist.  This is due to a fundamental property of logarithms in mathematics, that

- LOG10(10)= 1
- LOG10(1) = 0
- LOG10(.1)=-1

Therefore, when you perform a log10 of zero, it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution works partially, The problem now, That columns with value 1 are not showing in the graph. Attached a file for description,   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-z_MM1x1l0SaEpLODRDNHFmeVE/view?usp=sharing                                                        Maybe you have another solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried editing the vertical axis so the minimum value is zero instead of 'Auto'

Comment: I tried, it still not showing the column with a value of 1

Comment: Thanks it works well, another question, when i received a lot of data for a value in horizontal axis, the chart look very dense,it is possible to give more space to some value in horizontal axis, because now all the values get the same space. attachment file with the description.                                                                                      https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-z_MM1x1l0SMVVnZnpnTGtoaEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As you note yourself, I believe this is another question, and can be best answered as a new SO question.  I will be more than willing to help you solve this when it is in a new question.  This is to keep discrete questions as separate items.